# Invalid syntax error using Python and classes in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, syntax, jupyter-notebook

Hi there I have the following code inside Jupyter Notebooks using Python 3:

[Python code inside Jupyter Notebooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3wyl.png)

When I type the same code into Python shell the same thing happens:

```
class SARDog(Dog):
    """Represent a search dog."""

    def__init__(self, name):
        """Initialize the sardog."""
        super().__init__(name)

    def search(self):
        """Simulate searching."""
        print(self.name + " is searching.")

    my_dog = SARDog('Willie')

    print(my_dog.name + " is a search dog.")
    my_dog.sit()
    my_dog.search()

    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

-

The red line displaying the syntax error comes next to the colon after (self, name):

I have tried restarting the kernel in Jupyter but obviously the code is having the same effect in another environment.

The code is from a beginners Python cheat sheet.

Will really appreciate any input thanks!

Comment: You need a space between `def` and  `__init__`

Comment: Also, this is nothing to do with Jupyter. Python is a language specification; invalid syntax is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

After the `__init__` you need to add

```
self.name = "your choice, can be a 'str' though"
```

So that `self.name` is defined